# how to Create new Record in QuikcBlox custome table

Tags: android, quickblox

Want to create new Record in QuickBlox Custom Table which allready created.
i have Follow the guideline [Url](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-android) and using below method, here i m using my Table name

```
HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    fields.put("User ID",String.valueOf(myID));
    fields.put("senderLoginID", ""+mylogin.toString());
    fields.put("receiverLoginID", ""+friendLogin.toString());
    fields.put("messages", messageString);

    fields.put("isRead", false);


QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = new QBCustomObject();
qbCustomObject.setClassName("Movie");  // your Class name
qbCustomObject.setFields(fields);
QBCustomObjects.createObject(qbCustomObject, new QBCallbackImpl() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            QBCustomObjectResult qbCustomObjectResult = (QBCustomObjectResult) result;
            QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = qbCustomObjectResult.getCustomObject();
            Log.d("New record: ",newCustomObject.toString());
        } else {
            Log.e("Errors",result.getErrors().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Error getting Like

```
** '{"errors":{"base":["Forbidden. Need user."]}}'
… Request has been completed with error: [base Forbidden. Need user.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st off all, you don't need to use this

```
fields.put("User ID",String.valueOf(myID));
```

This field will be filled on the server based on your token information

Next, you have to be logged in in order to create record,
just do the next

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Sign_In_.26_Social_authorization